# How to use -Dinstallation.host= in intelliJ tomcat configuration without command line

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using mvn for build and deploy my code in tomcat. I am using command for build `clean install -DskipTests -DskipJangarooApp -pl :studio-webapp -am -T 4C` where studio-webapp is my module name.

And after build i use tomcat:run command like this :

```
tomcat7:run -Dinstallation.host=192.168.252.100
```

where 192.168.252.100 is my host machine IP. This process is running well.
But the problem is when I change any java class in my IntelliJ I again run buil command then run. And its taking so much time. So that I want to apply tomcat configuration in IntelliJ but i am not able to find any option of "-Dinstallation.host" in this screen
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what is not working. Do you want to run tomcat goal from IDE? Then as shown on the screen this is the correct place to add the jvm property for the maven goal.

Comment: I am using mvn configuration for build and run my project like :
build configuration in IntelliJ :
"clean install -DskipTests -DskipJangarooApp -pl :studio-webapp -am -T 4C"
tomcat run :
"tomcat7:run -Dinstallation.host=192.168.252.100"

I want to run this facility in tomcat server what is configured in IntelliJ so that I can build my project simultaneously.